# Don't allow edits over a certain percentage

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I really really really really like the new everyone can edit feature.  Heck, I've almost approved 1,000 of them.  But, some people don't understand how the system works, and could potentially cause 'harm' to the content of the site.

For an example, see these proposed edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/26225
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/26236

To help avoid this, I think editors (under 2k) should only be able to change 50% (or some percent) of a post.  This will prevent people for entirely mangling the meaning of a post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd rather have users that get their edits constantly rejected being banned from editing until they hit the 2k barrier. Have an approved edits percentage; if you're under 50% with more that 4-5 edits to your name, you should not be able to edit anything either until you really do have the right or for a predetermined period. Also, this should be explained somewhere near the edit button (because disappearing features are confusing).

Comment: 'users that get their edits constantly rejected being banned from editing' this already happens, actually

Comment: @YiJiang I wasn't aware of that. All the better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see with this is how does one determine "50%"? Something like putting a large code example in a codebox changes most every line but wouldn't be a huge edit.

If the edit isn't in the spirit of the original then it should simply be rejected.

Comment: @Bill, they somehow set a lower limit.  I can assume they should be able to set an upper limit as well.

Comment: @jjnguy: But the lower limit is "number of changed characters", not a percentage.

Comment: p.s. A unicorn just tore its horn off of its head and threw it at your post.  That is how much it sucks. `:P` (I should remind you that unicorns only have one horn, so this is a big deal.)

Comment: @Billy, well, you could easily count changed characters, and divide it by total characters to arrive at a percentage.

Comment: @jjnguy: Yeah, this question and answer really pissed them off.

Comment: @Billy, I suppose my question must also be terrible.  Good point.